# CalenderExtender control not working in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Calender Extender in asp.net web form page but its not showing me calender when I run the form and click in the text box or when control goes to the text box to which extender is related.
My design is as follows,

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_duedate" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="cal_duedate" TargetControlID="txt_duedate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgbtnCalendar"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

which is not working as expected,

Please help n thanks in Advance
Nils

Answer (score 0):

Add Script Manager or ToolkitScriptManger in your Page.

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

OR

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

Also Remove PopupButtonID="imgbtnCalendar" property from calender extender control. Setting this property means when you click on imgbtnCalendar then calender will show.